# How to extract Hierarchy till root from another table and leafs are present in another table? Using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

[This is the table which have hierarchy till root x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGPsF.png)

| Parent | Child |
| --- | --- |
| a | 45 |
| aaa | aa |
| aa | a |
| b | 55 |
| ee | e |
| x | bbb |
| bbb | bb |
| bb | b |
| eee | ee |
| x | ccc |
| ccc | cc |
| cc | c |
| x | eee |
| x | ddd |
| ddd | dd |
| dd | d |

[This is the table with nodes and parents which are present in 1st table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHXuM.png)

| Parent | Child |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 12 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 4 |
| d | 5 |

Now i want result containing leafs from second table connecting till root x.
Note - I dont want any hierarchy which is not related to leaf node present in table 2.

for eg. result should give result like

| Parent | Child |
| --- | --- |
| x | aaa |
| aaa | aa |
| aa | a |
| a | 1 |
| a | 12 |
| x | bbb |
| bbb | bb |
| bb | b |
| b | 3 |
| x | ccc |
| ccc | cc |
| cc | c |
| c | 4 |
| x | ddd |
| ddd | dd |
| dd | d |
| d | 5 |

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data (both as **TEXT** that can be copy/pasted and not as images); a detailed description of the problem; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and the expected output. At the moment, you expecti us to open the images, transcribe your data, interpret the two sentences where you describe the problem and then work out what the expected output is. Help us to help you and give us everything in a format we can use.

Comment: @ujwal: Did you try the answered code? I'd like to know if it works on your actual data. Regards...

Comment: @dr Thanks Buddy, work perfectly with my original data set with 10 M records.

Comment: @ujwal Glad to know that it is usefull. Regards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit confusing to me too, but here is one possibility to get it done (as I've got it). Basicaly, it is a step by step recursions with complicated order by clause to give the result you asked for. Regards...

```
WITH
    fltr AS         -- Filtering table
        (
            Select 'a' "PARENT",  '1'  "CHILD"  From DUAL   UNION ALL
            Select 'a' "PARENT",  '12' "CHILD"  From DUAL   UNION ALL
            Select 'b' "PARENT",  '3'  "CHILD"  From DUAL   UNION ALL
            Select 'c' "PARENT",  '4'  "CHILD"  From DUAL   UNION ALL
            Select 'd' "PARENT",  '5'  "CHILD"  From DUAL 
        ),
    nodes AS
        (
            Select 'a'    "PARENT",   '45'  "CHILD"     From DUAL   UNION ALL
            Select 'aaa'  "PARENT",     'aa'  "CHILD"   From DUAL   UNION ALL
            Select 'x'    "PARENT",     'aaa' "CHILD"   From DUAL   UNION ALL
            Select 'aa'   "PARENT",     'a'   "CHILD"   From DUAL   UNION ALL
            Select 'b'    "PARENT",   '55'  "CHILD"     From DUAL    UNION ALL
            Select 'ee'   "PARENT",     'e'   "CHILD"   From DUAL     UNION ALL
            Select 'x'    "PARENT",     'bbb' "CHILD"   From DUAL   UNION ALL
            Select 'bbb'  "PARENT",     'bb'  "CHILD"   From DUAL   UNION ALL
            Select 'bb'   "PARENT",     'b'   "CHILD"   From DUAL   UNION ALL
            Select 'eee'  "PARENT",     'ee'  "CHILD"   From DUAL   UNION ALL
            Select 'x'    "PARENT",     'ccc' "CHILD"   From DUAL     UNION ALL
            Select 'ccc'  "PARENT",     'cc'  "CHILD"   From DUAL     UNION ALL
            Select 'cc'   "PARENT",     'c'   "CHILD"   From DUAL   UNION ALL
            Select 'x'    "PARENT",     'eee' "CHILD"   From DUAL   UNION ALL
            Select 'x'    "PARENT",     'ddd' "CHILD"   From DUAL   UNION ALL
            Select 'ddd'  "PARENT",     'dd'  "CHILD"   From DUAL   UNION ALL
            Select 'dd'   "PARENT",     'd'   "CHILD"   From DUAL
        ),
--  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
    end_level AS
        (  
            Select Distinct
                f.PARENT "PARENT", 
                f.CHILD "CHILD"
            From  
                fltr f
            Left Join
                nodes n ON(1=1)
            Where 
                n.PARENT = 'x'
        ),
    midend AS
        (
            SELECT
                n.PARENT,
                n.CHILD
            FROM
                end_level e
            LEFT JOIN
                nodes n ON(n.CHILD = e.PARENT)
        ),
    midroot AS
        (
            SELECT
                n.PARENT,
                n.CHILD
            FROM
                midend e
            LEFT JOIN
                nodes n ON(n.CHILD = e.PARENT)
        )
SELECT DISTINCT 
    PARENT,
    CHILD
FROM 
    (
        SELECT PARENT, CHILD FROM NODES WHERE PARENT = 'x' And SubStr(CHILD, 1, 1) IN(SELECT PARENT FROM fltr) UNION ALL
        SELECT PARENT, CHILD FROM midroot UNION ALL
        SELECT PARENT, CHILD FROM midend UNION ALL
        SELECT PARENT, CHILD FROM end_level
    )
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN SubStr(PARENT, 1, 1) = 'x' 
            THEN LPAD(SubStr(CHILD, 1, 1), 2, SubStr(CHILD, 1, 1))
        WHEN SubStr(PARENT, 1, 1) = SubStr(CHILD, 1, 1)
            THEN LPAD(SubStr(CHILD, 1, 1), 3, SubStr(CHILD, 1, 1)) || To_Char(10 - Length(CHILD))
        WHEN SubStr(PARENT, 1, 1) = SubStr(CHILD, 1, 1)
            THEN LPAD(SubStr(CHILD, 1, 1), 4, SubStr(CHILD, 1, 1)) || CHILD
    ELSE
        LPAD(SubStr(PARENT, 1, 1), 5, SubStr(PARENT, 1, 1)) || CHILD
    END
--  
--  R e s u l t 
--  
--      PARENT CHILD
--      ------ -----
--      x      aaa   
--      aaa    aa    
--      aa     a     
--      a      1     
--      a      12    
--      x      bbb   
--      bbb    bb    
--      bb     b     
--      b      3     
--      x      ccc   
--      ccc    cc    
--      cc     c     
--      c      4     
--      x      ddd   
--      ddd    dd    
--      dd     d     
--      d      5
```

It can go deeper the same way and the only limiting thing is fixed value 'x' for root, but it is explicitly stated in the question so...